# Click On Element That Has 'x-onclick' with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium to click on an element with `x-onclick` property not `onclick`. [image: Screenshot of it]

I am using this element's xPath to click on it. These are the methods I have tried:

`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

`element.click()`

but these don't work. I would love if someone can tell me a solution.

Comment: Are you able to click on the element manually?

Comment: yes, I am able to click on it

Comment: Can you show your selenium command where you locating this element with XPath and a link to this specific page on https://eductin.com/ site?

Comment: Prophet this is the link [link](https://rtilinks.com/?b198880a14=UG01cnJJL1ljZVpWTk9uTjNHQjZjcy91aXlIZkcvTVRhbW4vWDFsWVhyVlJrQ0hNQ1dwVmJkWG1yN2lYQ0k1Q1FzRTJobEFEd2lObDdsemZrK3NVUUxPVnk0N1JpdFFZbVMwc1lkNTI2NUxoNnNTbXdWSFFNckdiNHlLQmFsTmRDaG8zZG1YK2dLdDhGblQvZ1k0bmV3PT0=) I am able to click on `i am not a robot button` but after it i am not able to click on generate button after waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tried this

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

`element` is a `web element`. I do not know if you have defined it or not. If not defined then you must have got **compile time error.**

Anyway this looks to me an angular based application. So I would try with below code trials :

There are 4 ways to click in **Selenium**.

I will use this `xpath`

```
//a[@id='generater' and @x-onclick]
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='generater' and @x-onclick]").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='generater' and @x-onclick]"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='generater' and @x-onclick]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='generater' and @x-onclick]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Thank you! Writing the xPath with @x-onclick worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Have you tried to click by creating xpath by using tag 'a' and 'id' by using simple selenium webdriver click method.

    ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='generater']")
    ele.click()

    or

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='generater']").click()  



if above xpath is unique then it should work else use javascript for clicking on above element 'ele'.
```